# how vector.empty() works?

Tags: c++, vector

i'm tying to check if a specific vector element is initialized...
i *googled* it and i found `vector::empty`
but it seems it doesn't work for me because it keeps returning `true` at any circumstances!!!

```
int main() {
int n, k;
cin >> n >> k;
auto tasks = new vector<list<int> *>(n);
tasks->insert(tasks->begin(), new list<int>);
tasks->insert(tasks->begin() + 1, new list<int>);
tasks->insert(tasks->begin() + 2, new list<int>);
tasks->insert(tasks->begin() + 3, new list<int>);
tasks->insert(tasks->begin() + 4, new list<int>);
if (tasks->at(2)->empty()) cout << "empty";
return 0;}
```

it keeps printing "empty"!!!

Comment: You are calling `empty` on the internal `list`, which *is* empty.

Comment: `new vector<list<int> *>(n);` nope nope nope nope. Please no!

Comment: In addition this should have become clear when checking the variables using the debugger.

Comment: to call empty of the vector (not of your list), `if (tasks -> empty()) cout << "empty";`

Comment: You almost *never* need a pointer to a standard container. Are you coming from a language where you must use `new` to create objects (like Java or C#)? In C++ it's not needed. Do e.g. `vector<list<int>> tasks(n);` to create a single vector object with `n` elements, each element being a list of integers. And generally, unless you have specific requirements the "default" container should always be `std::vector`.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what `empty` does. It checks if a vector is empty (i.e. it's size is zero), it's doesn't check if a particular element is initialised. Vector elements are always initialised, so there is no check for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not calling `std::vector::empty()`, you call `std::list::empty()`.

You insert 5 empty lists at the beginning of a vector, and then you call `empty()` on list at index 2.

---

Side note: Your vector is created with `n` lists and then you insert 5 more. Are you sure this is intended behaviour?

Also, using `insert()` is inefficient. Since all of your lists are empty, it doesn't matter where you will insert new ones, so you can add them at the end as well. You can do so by resizing the vector:

```
auto tasks = vector<list<int>>(n);
tasts.resize(n+5); //or just construct vector with n+5 lists initially
if (tasks.at(2).empty()) cout << "empty";
```

---

Side note 2: you are using far too much `new`. Make your life easier and stop it:

```
auto tasks = vector<list<int>>(n);
tasks.insert(tasks.begin(), list<int>{});
tasks.insert(tasks.begin() + 1, list<int>{});
tasks.insert(tasks.begin() + 2, list<int>{});
tasks.insert(tasks.begin() + 3, list<int>{});
tasks.insert(tasks.begin() + 4, list<int>{});
if (tasks.at(2).empty()) cout << "empty";
```

Comment: `push_back` would be better

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings `resize()` would be even better, I'll add that.

Comment: thank u very much! and sorry for that noobly code XD. im new to this u know :)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `empty()` on the third element of the vector, which is of type `std::list*` and also has an `empty()` member function.

Your code prints "empty", because the list at index 2 of your vector is empty.